# CSS rearranges the second time on Angular Ionic App

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm building an Angular&ionic app, on Chrome debug everyting looks fine but when i'm deploying it the page styling looks fine on the first instance, but when i'm going back and returning to the page the the css seems to get messed up.

first instance:
[first instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trSBu.png)

[second (notice the icons in the middle):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lprR.png)

my html:`

```
<div class="infoButtons">
                    <div>
                        <i class="icon ion-icon-location positive" ></i>
                        <p>{{event.location}} <br> {{event.city}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="priceBtn" ng-show="{{event.price}}" style="padding-right:10%;">
                        <i class="icon ion-icon-shekel positive" id="nisIcon"></i>
                        <p><span>שׁ״ח&nbsp</span>{{event.price}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <i class="ion-icon-17 positive" style="margin-bottom:3%"></i>
                        <p>{{event.date}} <br> {{event.hour}}</p>               
                    </div>          
                </div>

            </div>
```

my scss (all committed):`

```
    .infoButtons{
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: space-around !important;
    padding-right:10% !important;   

    div{

        margin-bottom: 10%;
        margin-top: 5%;
        margin-right:10% !important;
        margin-left:10% !important;
        display: flex !important;
        flex-direction: column !important;
        align-items: center !important;
        height:70px !important;

        i{
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: 100;
            margin-bottom: 3%;

        }

        p{
            text-align: center!important;
            white-space: nowrap !important;
            font-size:13px;                     
        }

    }

    #priceBtn{
        p{
            display: flex;
        }
    }

}
```

help please!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
.infoButtons{
   display: flex !important;
   justify-content: space-around !important;
 }
.infoButtons div{
    flex-grow: 0.33;
    flex-basis: 33%;

    height: 70px !important;
    text-align: center;
    height:70px !important;

    i{
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 100;
        margin-bottom: 3%;

    }

    p{
        text-align: center!important;
        white-space: nowrap !important;
        font-size:13px;                     
    }
```